# Has the British Government acted illegally in revoking Shamima Begum's citizenship?

Tags: united-kingdom, international-law, citizenship

Under international law, it is illegal to revoke a citizen's citizenship leaving them stateless.

The British government, after a journalist discovered Shamima Begum, a British citizen, in a refugee camp in Iraq, revoked her citizenship. She was a number of British schoolgirls who had left Britain to join ISIS.

The British government said at the time they understood her to have dual citizenship. She is of Bangladeshi heritage but the Bangladeshi government has said that she is not and never has been a citizen of Bangladesh.

In fact, she had the option of taking up dual nationality upto the age of 21 given that her parents were from there but she had never lived there. She is now 23.

Given international law, has the British Government acted illegally?

Comment: Law SE is probably a slightly better place to ask this. And it was asked there before https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/37463/is-revoking-citizenship-for-affiliation-with-a-terrorist-group-a-violation-of-in it seems.

Comment: OTOH there are some recent [developments](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-64731007) which someone might to summarize here, although they don't seem political to me (whether she was trafficked). But insofar her appeals were rejected.

Comment: This is indeed international law (specifically, the 1961 UN Convention on Statelessness) which the UK ratified, but Bangladesh didn't . Since it's indeed a treaty matter, this belongs on Law.SE.

Answer (score 4):

> Under international law, it is illegal to revoke a citizen's citizenship leaving them stateless.

There is no universal "international law" that prohibits revoking a citizen's citizenship leaving them stateless. There is the 1961 [Convention on the Reduction of Statelessness](https://legal.un.org/ilc/texts/instruments/english/conventions/6_1_1961.pdf), and article 8 paragraph 1 of that convention prohibits depriving citizenship if it would make them stateless (with some exceptions specified in article 8 paragraph 2):

> 1. A Contracting State shall not deprive a person of its nationality if such deprivation would render him stateless.

But less than half of the countries of the world are party to this convention (currently, it has only 75 parties), so this can hardly be said to be a general "international law". The UK is a party to this convention, so a better question would be whether the UK has acted in violation of the Convention on the Reduction of Statelessness.

Various provisions of the convention have been incorporated into domestic British law. Specifically, the provision prohibiting revoking citizenship if it will make the person stateless is found in [section 40](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/61/section/40)(4) of the British Nationality Act 1981 (as amended):

> (4) The Secretary of State may not make an order under subsection (2)
> if he is satisfied that the order would make a person stateless.

where section 40(2) is what allows the British government to deprive a British citizen of British citizenship:

> (2) The Secretary of State may by order deprive a person of a
> citizenship status if the Secretary of State is satisfied that
> deprivation is conducive to the public good.

(Though it should be noted that section 40(4A) provides a slightly looser restriction on deprivation of citizenship of *naturalized* British citizens -- their citizenship can be deprived even if it will them stateless, as long as they are able to become national of another country. I am not sure if this provision complies with the Convention. In any case, this is not relevant to Shamima Begum's case as she was not a British citizen by naturalization.)

> but the Bangladeshi government has said that she is not and never has
> been a citizen of Bangladesh.

This seems inconsistent with my reading of Bangladesh's nationality law. Bangladesh's [Citizenship Act 1951](http://bdlaws.minlaw.gov.bd/act-242.html) (which was inherited from Pakistan's Citizenship Act 1951, with amendments to make it specific to Bangladesh after independence), [section 5](http://bdlaws.minlaw.gov.bd/act-242/section-7472.html), provides that a child born abroad to a father who was a Bangladeshi citizen otherwise than by descent, automatically acquires Bangladeshi citizenship at birth:

> 5. Subject to the provisions of section 3 a person born after the commencement of this Act, shall be a citizen of Bangladesh by descent
>    if his 1[father or mother] is a citizen of Bangladesh at the time of
>    his birth:
>
> Provided that if the 2[father or mother] of such person is a citizen
> of Bangladesh by descent only, that person shall not be a citizen of
> Bangladesh by virtue of this section unless-
>
> (a) that person's birth having occurred in a country outside
> Bangladesh the birth is registered at a Bangladesh Consulate or
> Mission in that country, or where there is no Bangladesh Consulate or
> Mission in that country at the prescribed Consulate or Mission or at a
> Bangladesh Consulate or Mission in the country nearest to that
> country; or
>
> (b) that person's 3[father or mother] is, at the time of the birth, in
> the service of any Government in Bangladesh.

The part after "Provided that" applies only to cases where the parent was a Bangladeshi citizen by descent. In such cases, registration of the child is necessary for the child to acquire Bangladeshi citizenship. However, when the parent was a Bangladeshi citizen "otherwise than by descent" (e.g. by birth in Bangladesh or by naturalization), only the part before "Provided that" applies, and thus the child is automatically a Bangladeshi citizen at birth, without needing registration or any other action.

Prior to 2008, it was "father" instead of "father and mother". Since Shamima Begum was born before 2008, we should only be considering her father's status. I believe that her father was a Bangladeshi citizen otherwise than by descent.

There were [several other cases](http://siac.decisions.tribunals.gov.uk/Documents/outcomes/documents/C3,C4%20&%20C7%20-%20Open%20Judgment%20-%2018.03.2021%20-%20JA.pdf) of attempted revocation of British citizenship of children of Bangladeshis that were deemed to have been illegal by British courts, because it would make them stateless. However, the distinction between those cases and Shamima Begum's case is that the UK attempted to revoke their British citizenship after they turned 21, whereas the UK attempted to revoke Begum's British citizenship before she turned 21. [Section 14](http://bdlaws.minlaw.gov.bd/act-242/section-7481.html) of Bangladesh's Citizenship Act provides for dual nationals to automatically cease to have Bangladeshi citizenship, but it does not apply to people under 21:

> 14. (l) Subject to the provisions of this section if any person is a citizen of Bangladesh under the provisions of this Act, and is at the
>     same time a citizen or national of any other country, he shall, unless
>     he makes a declaration according to the laws of that other country
>     renouncing his status as citizen or national thereof, cease to be a
>     citizen of Bangladesh.
>
> (1A) Nothing in sub-section (1) applies to a person who has not
> attained twenty-one years of his age.
>
> (2) Nothing in sub-section (1) shall apply to any person who is a
> subject of an Acceding State so far as concerns his being a subject of
> that State.

So the people in those other cases also had dual British and Bangladeshi citizenship at birth, but they automatically lose their Bangladeshi citizenship when they turned 21, by operation of section 14 of Bangladesh's Citizenship Act, and therefore the UK can no longer revoke their British citizenship. However, Shamima Begum had not yet turned 21 when the UK made an order revoking her British citizenship, and therefore she still had Bangladeshi citizenship at that time, so she should not be stateless after the revocation.

I am not aware of any credible legal reasoning provided by the Bangladeshi government for why they claim that she was not a Bangladeshi citizen. [One press release](https://mofa.gov.bd/site/press_release/a5530623-ad80-4996-b0b4-f60f39927005) from the Bangladeshi Ministry of Foreign Affairs says:

> Bangladesh asserts that Ms. Shamima Begum is not a Bangladeshi
> citizen. She is a British citizen by birth and has never applied for
> dual nationality with Bangladesh.

But the fact that she "has never applied for dual nationality" does not support the assertion that she is not a Bangladeshi citizen. From the section 5 of the law quoted above, an "application for dual nationality" (or any other kind of application) is not necessary for her to be automatically a Bangladeshi citizen at birth, if her father was a Bangladeshi citizen otherwise than by descent. And her dual citizenship did not cause her to cease being a Bangladeshi citizen before she turned 21 (when the order revoking her British citizenship was made), even without any "application for dual citizenship". Since she turned 21 after the order revoking her British citizenship, she should only have had Bangladeshi citizenship at that time, and thus she should not have lost Bangladeshi citizenship due to dual nationality.

The Bangladeshi ministers are not the ultimate arbiters of what Bangladeshi law means; it is Bangladeshi courts that interpret Bangladeshi law. Bangladeshi ministers can be sometimes wrong about Bangladeshi law, just like British ministers are sometimes wrong about British law, and the British government sometimes loses cases in court. So the Bangladeshi government's statement must be taken as just one position, that needs to be judged on the merits of its legal reasoning and consistency with the text of the law and existing legal Bangladeshi legal precedents, and not taken as a definitely correct statement of Bangladeshi law.

I am not aware of any Bangladeshi court ruling regarding the subject of whether Shamima Begum had Bangladeshi citizenship at the time of the revocation of her British citizenship. Nor do I think there will likely be such a court ruling, since both Begum and the Bangladeshi government take the position that she did not have Bangladeshi citizenship, and I can't imagine any likely situation where any other party would bring a case in Bangladeshi court arguing that she did have Bangladeshi citizenship.

---

One interesting question is, let's say hypothetically, at some point in the future, the Bangladeshi courts make a final ruling at some point in the future that says Shamima Begum was not a Bangladeshi citizen at the time of the revocation of British citizenship. (I don't know what the reasoning in this hypothetical ruling would be, but let's suppose that they interpret section 5 to require an application or registration for citizenship by descent, even in the case of a parent who is a Bangladeshi citizen otherwise than by descent, despite the text saying that the child "shall" be a Bangladeshi citizen without conditions.) One might ask, would that be sufficient to make the revocation of Shamima Begum's British citizenship illegal under British law or a violation of the Convention. My opinion is that it shouldn't, if the ruling is not consistent with existing law and precedent at the time of the revocation.

I acknowledge that each country has the right to interpret its own laws in its own way, and the exact same text may be interpreted by different countries to have different meanings. A country can change its law at any time, and can change its interpretation of a law at any time, for any reason, even if it's a political reason. If Bangladeshi courts were to interpret that section 5 requires registration even for children of citizens otherwise than by descent, then I agree that other countries should follow that interpretation in determining whether someone has Bangladeshi citizenship for cases from now on.

However, retroactively applying such a ruling to past cases is problematic. This is because it is possible for a country (especially one where the judiciary is not independent) to deliberately misinterpret its law to advance a political purpose. (I am not suggesting that Bangladesh does this, but just that it is possible for a country to do this.) Even in countries where the judiciary is ostensibly independent, there are still sometimes accusations of political influence, or cases where it overrules its previous precedents. Imagine a Country A that prohibits dual nationals from being elected; a malicious Country B can suddenly interpret that Country A's officials were actually Country B citizens from birth (even if they had no connection to Country B); if Country A had to follow that interpretation, then it would retroactively disqualify its own officials.

Especially in a case where a person is "unwanted", a country may have a political incentive to interpret its law after the fact to claim that the person was not its national, to prevent having to take the person when another country revokes the person's citizenship. If a future ruling from another country of citizenship can retroactively invalidate a past revocation of citizenship, then there would never be a final resolution in the legality of a case of revocation of citizenship, as, even in a case where it appears that a person's other citizenship is obvious and certain, one will still need to beware of the potential for the other country to reinterpret it in the opposite way for political reasons in the future. The legality of an action (e.g. the revocation of citizenship) should not depend on future events.

If a court interpretation is sufficiently inconsistent with past precedents and sources of law, then it should be viewed as effectively a change in the law. Countries are allowed to change their law (including via re-interpretation), of course, but it should not affect other countries retroactively. For example, if Bangladeshi courts make a ruling that Shamima Begum does not have Bangladeshi citizenship, and if it is inconsistent with previous sources of law which say that she did have Bangladeshi citizenship, then it can be viewed as effectively a revocation of her Bangladeshi citizenship. If this "revocation" (i.e. the inconsistent ruling) happened after the British revocation of her British citizenship, then it should not affect the legality of the prior British revocation. In this view, it would be Bangladesh that made her stateless, not the UK.

Therefore, for revocation of citizenship to be functional, for the statelessness determination, the revoking country should only need to consider other countries' sources of law from before the revocation. In this case, the UK should make a good faith effort to interpret the Bangladeshi law based on existing Bangladeshi sources of law from prior to the revocation, consulting Bangladeshi precedents and consulting experts in how Bangladeshi law has been interpreted in the past. If they determine that she had Bangladeshi citizenship according to their examination of existing Bangladeshi sources of law from prior to the revocation, that should satisfy the provision in British law that the revocation not make her stateless.

Of course, Bangladeshi courts could disagree. Bangladeshi courts could say that their ruling is simply a reflection of how Bangladeshi law should always have been interpreted in the past, and there was no change in interpretation. In that case, we have a he-said/she-said situation, where different countries disagree on what the law of one of them used to be. The Convention basically breaks down in situations like this. Article 14 of the Convention provides that disputes between contracting states be submitted to the International Court of Justice by one of the parties, but Bangladesh is not a party to the Convention, so I don't think that this dispute can be submitted in that way. (Furthermore, it would be awkward for Bangladesh to represent Shamima Begum, who Bangladesh claims was never its national.) And I don't see any mechanism for an individual to bring a challenge to a state on the basis of the Convention.

If we let one country interpret another country's law unilaterally, we could have the opposite type of abuse -- i.e. a country says that it is not making someone stateless when revoking citizenship (by falsely interpreting another country's law to claim that the person has that country's nationality). But I don't see much point in doing this -- the Convention is voluntary, and a party can denounce the convention and withdraw from it anyway. So there is no need to use some backhanded way to violate the Convention.

Comment: On the topic of British courts interpreting Bangladeshi law - this is done by calling expert witnesses, and the court's conclusions are findings of fact rather than law. This means that their findings do not create case law; future cases cannot rely on a British court's previous findings on foreign law in similar circumstances

Answer (score 1):

**No**, it was legal because at the time when the UK citizenship has been taken away she was eligible for the Bangladesh citizenship.

I would provide some context below, to help understanding what went on.

In June 2014, the extremist group ISIS launched a global social media recruitment campaign, targeting also women, including teenagers. An unprecedented number of young men and women from Western
countries (i.e., United States, United Kingdom, Australia) responded to online campaigns and made attempts
to travel to Syria and join ISIS militants, with many arriving successfully. [Here](https://ijoc.org/index.php/ijoc/article/viewFile/13103/2935) there is a good detailed article with analysis, how it has been done.

Shamima Begum was one of three teenage girls from London who traveled to Syria in 2015 to join the Islamic State, for the reason "because I was young and naive" as she later commented on. The British home secretary at the time, Sajid Javid, revoked her citizenship, citing national security risks. The court ruled that, though there were different opinions about whether her travel to Syria had been voluntary, the government was within its rights to revoke her British citizenship. “You can still be a risk of setting off a bomb in London or in Manchester even if you have been trafficked at a young age.”

The court found that stripping Ms. Begum of her UK citizenship **was lawful** ([source](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/02/22/world/europe/shamima-begum-uk-citizenship-isis.html)) because she was “a citizen of Bangladesh by descent” as her mother was born there and would not, therefore, be left stateless. British citizenship can be removed by the secretary of state, but not if to do so would render the subject stateless. Many citizens of the United Kingdom are immune from deprivation action for that reason, but not Ms. Begum.

Officials in Bangladesh said she never applied for dual nationality with Bangladesh and had never visited the country. Looks like UK officials interpret that it is enough that an individual is **eligible** for citizenship elsewhere ([source](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-47312207)). Lawyers have told the BBC that under Bangladesh law, a UK national born to a Bangladeshi parent is automatically a Bangladeshi citizen - a dual national.

Under this "blood line" law, Bangladeshi nationality and citizenship lapse when a person reaches the age of 21, unless they make active efforts to retain it. The UK citizenship has been removed when she was 19 ([source](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-47312207)), so the action has been valid at the time. It would not have been now.

Ms. Begum is now 23 so it is formally too late. But looks like the Bangladeshi citizenship was the last citizenship remaining so I doubt if the Bangladesh really had the right to revoke it that they think they did after passing the 21 year threshold. I understand they interpreted the inaction as refusal of the citizenship, but it may have not been legal for them to accept that refusal.

Comment: Being eligible for citizenship isn't the same as having citizenship and would cause a person to be stateless.

Comment: @JoeW That's not the case. The UK courts have decided that it is the same in this case. You may think they should have decided differently, but they didn't.

Comment: @DJClayworth And when a country revokes citizenship based on someone being eligible in another country and that country refuses to grant citizenship that person is still stateless. Just because someone is eligible for something doesn't mean they will be able to get it.

Comment: That's your opinion but the UK courts disagree.

Comment: Wasn't she not merely eligible but actually a citizen of Bangladesh *at birth*, since at least one parent was a citizen?  http://bdlaws.minlaw.gov.bd/act-242/section-7472.html

Comment: She was, but her citizenship lapsed at 21 in accordance with normal Bangladeshi law, meaning that the British decision foreseeably made her stateless. That assumes that one does not view the Bangladeshi government's contemporaneous denial that she was a citizen at all as having left her without Bangladeshi citizenship even then.

Comment: @DJClayworth thus the UK courts have upheld a government action that was illegal.

Comment: Whose authority are you using to say that the court was "illegal"?

Comment: @Obie2.0, it seems that if she had wanted to avoid being stateless, she could have tried to avoid it by trying to actually become a Bangladeshi citizen, with a good chance of success. Well, more than zero chance. And it seems that Bangladesh never refused her citizenship when she was entitled to it, because she never applied.

Comment: @gnasher729 - The Bangladeshi government denied that she had citizenship when she might have been entitled to it, in no uncertain terms. That seems a lot like denying her citizenship. If anything, they deprived her of her citizenship first, but that hardly absolves Britain of the need to uphold their own laws and not render anyone stateless.

Comment: @Obie2.0: "She was, but her citizenship lapsed at 21 in accordance with normal Bangladeshi law, meaning that the British decision foreseeably made her stateless." The UK revoked her British citizenship before she turned 21, so the British revocation did not make her stateless as she still has Bangladeshi citizenship at that time. And since she no longer had British citizenship when she turned 21, she would not have lost Bangladeshi citizenship at age 21, according to Bangladeshi law.

Comment: @DJClayworth I was not making a judgement on the decision being legal or not, just a statement that being eligible for citizenship elsewhere doesn't mean you actually have it. If it is shown she wasn't just eligible for citizenship but was a citizen that would change my comment.

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest that it even may even violate *British* law, as suggested in [the *very court ruling*](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/02/22/world/europe/shamima-begum-uk-citizenship-isis.html) that upheld the decision removing Begum's British citizenship:

> “British citizenship is not an absolute entitlement for everyone,” the
> court said. “It can be removed by the secretary of state, but **not if
> to do so would render the subject stateless.** Many citizens of the
> United Kingdom are immune from deprivation action for that reason, but
> not Ms. Begum.”

The court appears to be under the impression that Begum is also a Bangladeshi national, but an [article from 2019](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-47312207) suggests that Bangladeshi citizenship via the route through which Begum would have had it "expires" unless legal proceedings are taken to retain it:

> Lawyers have told the BBC that under Bangladesh law, a UK national
> born to a Bangladeshi parent is automatically a Bangladeshi citizen -
> a dual national - but the Bangladeshi authorities assert that's not
> the case for Ms Begum.
>
> Under this "blood line" law, Bangladeshi nationality and citizenship
> lapse when a person reaches the age of 21, unless they make active
> efforts to retain it.
>
> So, it is Ms Begum's age, 19, that is likely - in part - to have given
> Home Office lawyers and the home secretary reassurance there was a
> legal basis for stripping her of her UK citizenship.

As of today, Begum would have to be at least 23, and the court does not seem to have claimed that she took efforts to retain  her Bangladeshi nationality, so the decision to do so would seem to have rendered her stateless, seemingly making the decision improper by the very standard upheld in the court's decision. Note also that even around the time that she would have been entitled to Bangladeshi nationality by virtue of descent, the Bangladeshi government *denied* that she was a citizen, which *de facto* could be viewed as stripping her of her Bangladeshi citizenship.

It likely also violates international law. On the one hand, while it certainly goes against the spirit of laws such as the [Convention Relating to the Status of Stateless Persons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_Relating_to_the_Status_of_Stateless_Persons), this convention also says that:

> It [the Convention] does not apply to those who have demonstrated
> themselves to have been enemies of international peace and
> co-operation.

This vague clause could easily be used to deny the protection of its provisions to someone who had been a member of an organization such as ISIS. However, the [Universal Declaration of Human Rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Declaration_of_Human_Rights) has no such proviso, and indicates that:

> Everyone has the right to a nationality.

While the British court system may try to defend its decision within its own legal framework by arguing that she had a *route* to a nationality at the time of the *original* decision, when she was 19, the plain meaning of the UDHR indicates that people have a right to a nationality at all times, suggesting that Britain, Bangladesh, or both may well be in violation of this provision.

Comment: -1: I am asking about international law. International law is not international if also member states do not enact subsidiary law that supports it.

Comment: She does not have a route to Bangladeshi nationality as the Bangladeshi government has said, given that she belonged to a terrorist party, she would face the death penalty if she ever came to Bangladesh.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - Well, do feel free to downvote an answer that emphatically agrees with you on all points! That *is* your prerogative. Did you actually read it, or did you assume that because I have sometimes disagreed with you on other questions, this answer must also be in disagreement? I fear it is the latter, since you missed the part where I said that it was likely in violation of the UDHR *and* Britain's own interpretation of it, as well as pointing out that she could be viewed as having been stripped of her Bangladeshi citizenship.